# Точка после каждого слова (или тире)

Tags: интонация

— Отдай. Мне. Эту. Вещь.
После каждого слова — пауза, то есть как бы идёт «расчленение» предложения на отдельные слова (членораздельно произносить), чтобы лучше понял собеседник, и мне интересно, как эту интонацию можно грамотно передать на письме: не иначе как точками. 
В «Гарри Поттере и Ордене Феникса» вышло так:
— ТОГДА — Я — НЕ — ХОЧУ — БЫТЬ — ЧЕЛОВЕКОМ! 
Но насколько правильно такое оформление? Можно ли написать таким образом: 
— Отдай — мне — эту — вещь.
Ведь не ставить же запятые и многоточия после каждого слова! 
Какой вариант лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полностью согласна с предыдущим ответом (проголосовала за него), кроме ненормативности тире. Выделение парцеллята скобками и тире, конечно, скорее **авторские знаки**, чем общепринятые, но не ошибка. Пунктуация при использовании писателем парцелляции — вообще авторское решение. Не имея строгой регламентации, литераторы вправе выбирать такой вариант, который, по их мнению, точнее передает суть описываемого и лучше подходит к контексту.

Источник: http://infoogle.ru/chto_takoe_parcellyaciya.html

Встречается даже  слоговая парцелляция, которая осуществляется в предложении, состоящем из одного слова. Напр.:
Лолита, свет моей жизни, огонь моих чресел. Грех мой, душа моя. Ло-ли-та: кончик языка совершает путь в три шажка вниз по небу, чтобы на третьем толкнуться о зубы. Ло. Ли. Та (В. Набоков).

«Оди – накового

моря — рыбы! Взмах!

… Мертвой раковиной

Губы на губах» (М. И. Цветаева)

В Вашем случае тоже возможно тире, но большей экспрессии можно достичь с помощью восклицательного знака, смотря как произнести:  — Отдай! Мне! Эту! Вещь!  Если просто раздельно, но на одном тоне, лучше тире.

Answer (score 5):

Этот стилистический прием называется парцелляция. На письме предложение разбивается на отдельные части с помощью любых знаков, которые могут стоять в конце предложения: точки, многоточия, восклицательного или вопросительного знака.

> Когда избавит нас творец от шляпок их! чепцов! и шпилек! и булавок! И
> книжных и бисквитных лавок! (Грибоедов)
>
> Я? Вам? Дал телефон? Что за ерунда! — не понимая, сказал Никитин. (Юрий Бондарев)
>
> Мы время проведем
> у печки. В Имеретии. Зимою.
> Как в Переделкине, как под Москвою. (Вера Инбер)

Разбиение посредством тире не является нормативным. В вашем случае следует написать так:

> Отдай. Мне. Эту. Вещь!

Или, если хотите выразить бóльшую экспрессию:

> Отдай! Мне! Эту! Вещь!